# Is there a way to establish ownership roles in the API Publisher?

Tags: wso2-api-manager

Our company has several organizations within it.  We'd like our API Owners to be responsible for publishing their APIs via the publisher.  However, my current understanding is that if you have the ability to publish an API, you get the ability to publish all APIs in the system.

Is it possible to establish publisher roles by team, and the appropriate ownership of APIs?

For example:

Team 1 owns APIs A,B,C
Team 2 owns APIs X,Y,Z

A member of Team 1 can only edit/publish A,B,C.

Thanks

Comment: Same question is answered here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/42017990/3176125

Comment: Thanks, I had searched... but didn't find this one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WSO2 APIM security - separation of the publisher access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42003881/wso2-apim-security-separation-of-the-publisher-access)

Answer (score 0):

[WSO2 API Manager support publisher access control.](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/design-api/advanced-topics/enable-publisher-access-control-in-api-publisher-portal/) With that, you can define role-based access control to your APIs. So you can enable read/update(publish) restrictions to user groups with roles.